# Python how to realize keeping cmdA executing till cmdB an cmdC finished

Tags: python

I want to record some information when cmd B and cmd C are being executed.
My idea is, executing cmd A(cmd A is mean to record information) before cmd B and cmd C start, then suspend cmd A when cmd B and cmd C are finished.
How to achieve it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could run the cmdB and cmdC functions from the cmdA function.

```
def cmdB():
     pass

def cmdC():
    pass


def cmdA():
    # start recording information
    print "recording started"
    #run cmdB
    cmdB()
    # run cmdC
    cmdC()
    # stop recording
    print "recording stopped"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cmdA()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will have a try.

Comment: If cmdA is used for writing information to a file, how to stop writing when cmdB and cmdC finished? For example, cmdA like "subprocess.Popen(cmd + ' > c:\\data\\test1.log')", actually, I don't know how to keep writing test1.log either.